# Relationship properties in Neo4j

Tags: csv, graph, properties, neo4j, relationships

I have a problem with relations on Neo4j. I have 3 files with the .csv extension to be loaded into Neo4j. The first two files are nodes that I already and successful created. The files are: forum_0.csv & person_0.csv and they got this headers:

idForum|titleForum|creationDateForum (forum_0.csv)

idPerson|firstNamePerson|lastNamePerson| ... (person_0.csv)

I successful create the two nodes but now I need to create a relation between these nodes. For that I need to load the third file, forum_hasMember_person_0.csv 
(and this file got this header:
idForum|idPerson|joinDateFHMP )

and my problem is at this point. I load the third file with this code:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_has_Member_person_0.csv" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
MATCH (forum:Forum(idForum: row.idForum))
MATCH (person:Person(idPerson: row.idPerson))
MERGE (forum)-[:FOR_HASMEMBER_PRS]->(person);
```

How can I create the FOR_HASMEMBER_PRS relation with "joinDateFHMP" property?
It's the only thing left on the relationship creation. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? I have also fixed some typos in your question's query.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_has_Member_person_0.csv" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
MATCH (forum:Forum {idForum: row.idForum})
MATCH (person:Person {idPerson: row.idPerson})
MERGE (forum)-[:FOR_HASMEMBER_PRS {joinDateFHMP: row.joinDateFHMP}]->(person);
```

Comment: Yeahh!! Your solution works!! Thanks mate ;)

Could ask you another question about relations in Neo4j?

Comment: You can always submit a new question.

Comment: Ok @cybersam I will follow your advice! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I like putting an identifier on the relationship and then using SET:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_has_Member_person_0.csv" AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
MATCH (forum:Forum {idForum: row.idForum})
MATCH (person:Person {idPerson: row.idPerson})
MERGE (forum)-[r:FOR_HASMEMBER_PRS]->(person)
SET r.joinDateFHMP = row.joinDateFHMP;
```

Comment: This error occurs when doing your code.


Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 5, column 18 (offset: 182))
"MATCH(forum:Forum(idForum: row.idForum))"
                  ^
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

How can I solve this?

Comment: Ah, I copy-pasted your code. It has syntax errors. Edited.

Comment: I have to try your solution, but I have to say that the previous answer from @cybersam works perfectly for me. And by the way, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, they are the same.